# Why does this line cause a syntax error for my .gitconfigure file?

Tags: git, git-config

I'm trying to set up my `git log` command to automatically format the way I want to. Under the `[pretty]` section, below, git says there is an error in my syntax but I don't understand what it is. I'm following the man page as closely as possible.

```
[alias]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        co = checkout                                                                                                                                                                                       
        stat = status                                                                                                                                                                                       
        l = log --all --graph --oneline                                                                                                                                                                     
        log = log --pretty=log_format                                                                                                                                                                       
[log]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        decorate = true                                                                                                                                                                                     
        abbrevCommit = true                                                                                                                                                                                 

[color]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        ui = true                                                                                                                                                                                           

[pretty]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        log_format = "%C(yellow)%h %an %ad%C(reset)%n%w(72,1,2)%s%b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[format]
    pretty = format:%C(yellow)%h %an %ad%C(reset)%n%w(72,1,2)%s%b
```